# Sqlite query Smarter Rows with mathematics of cloned tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite, math

Okay this is pretty complicated to even explain but I will try.

Buying table

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  itemId  amount  price   bought  collected slot  aborted playerHash
1   2607    4111    200600  0       0         0     0       1020628
2   11335   1       0       0       0         3     1       1020628
3   2495    6546    5306    0       0         1     0       1020628
4   1127    101     58300   101     0         5     0       37763265
5   14479   1       107500  0       0         2     0       37763265
6   1       100     1       0       0         0     0       3        *simulate a problem Buy
```

Selling table

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  itemId  amount  price   sold  collected slot  aborted  playerHash
1   8       8234    132950  7244  0         4     0        1020628
2   9       1980    132950  0     0         5     0        1020628
3   9       100     126300  0     0         2     0        1020628
4   3024    8888    10900   8888  0         0     0        37763265
5   1       100     1       1     0         0     0        1       *simulate a problem Sell
6   1       100     1       1     0         0     0        2       *simulate a problem Sell
```

Result of match ups

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S.itemId  S.amount  S.price  S.sold  S.collected  S.slot  S.playerHash  B.itemId  B.amount  B.price  B.bought  B.collected  B.slot  B.playerHash
123       2         444      1       0            0       15431         123       34535     448      3         0            1       3455
123       2         444      1       0            0       15431         123       7567      444      333       0            3       7651

*simulated result rows of wrong data

1         100       1        1       0            0       1             1         100       1        0         0            0       3
1         100       1        1       0            0       2             1         100       1        0         0            0       3
```

The query I'm trying to do has to match up Buyers of same itemId with Sellers of same itemId.
Has to make sure both Buyer and Seller didn't have aborted boolean set on their item.
Also process Buyers who paying more then what the Seller wants first.
Also check to make sure the amount Seller is selling hasn't been sold yet.
Also check to make sure the amount Buyer is buying hasn't been bought yet.
As well as process 100 sales per batch.

Query below works great for the most part.

Problem I'm trying to fix in the query is to make it more intelligent with mathematics.
Lets say Selling table had playerHash 1 and playerHash 2
itemId 8 with amount 100 and sold 1 listed by playerHash lets say 1.
itemId 8 with amount 100 and sold 1 listed by playerHash lets say 2.
Now there is 1 Buyer called playerHash 3 who is buying same itemId 8 and amount 100.

Problem now is 
playerHash1 can't sell all his 100 amount of itemId 8 because he only has 99 left (sold 1)
playerHash2 can't sell all his 100 amount of itemId 8 because he only has 99 left (sold 1) same story

Now the query should return
playerHash 1 selling to playerHash3 buyer with a new column to the end of row called something like willBuyAmount set it to 99
Next row should know that playerHash 1 has sold = 100 (without updating the database and without changing sold column in previous row)
Dsplay that playerHash 2 selling to playerHash3 buyer with a new coulmn to the end of row called something like willBuyAmount set it to 1.
playerHash2 should still be able to know by now that it has 98 left (sold 1) + 1 temporary somewhere idk clone the tables maybe?
and for future buyers of same itemId and >= price should be able to buy just 98 of this item amount left from playerHash2.

Here is the math I want to put into the query

```
VAR amountBuyerNeeds = (B.amount - B.bought)
VAR amountSellerStock = (S.amount - S.sold)
//update these values in the simulated cloned table data.
B.bought = IF(amountBuyerNeeds > amountSellerStock, (B.bought + amountSellerStock), B.amount)
S.sold = IF(amountSellerStock > amountBuyerNeeds, (S.sold + amountBuyerNeeds), S.amount)
//to real row print out
willBuyAmount = IF(amountBuyerNeeds > amountSellerStock, amountSellerStock, amountBuyerNeeds)
```

Query ATM looks like this.

```
SELECT S.itemId AS sell_itemId,
       S.amount AS sell_amount,
       S.price AS sell_price,
       S.sold AS sell_sold,
       S.collected AS sell_collected,
       S.slot AS sell_slot,
       S.playerHash AS sell_playerHash,
       B.itemId AS buy_itemId,
       B.amount AS buy_amount,
       B.price AS buy_price,
       B.bought AS buy_bought,
       B.collected AS buy_collected,
       B.slot AS buy_slot,
       B.playerHash AS buy_playerHash
  FROM Buying AS B, 
       Selling AS S
ON B.itemId = S.itemId 
AND
B.aborted = 0 
AND
S.aborted = 0 
AND
B.price >= S.price 
AND
S.sold < S.amount 
AND
B.bought < B.amount
 ORDER BY B.price DESC
 LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Yes you may be thinking why I used `mysql tag` with `sqlite` i didn't I used `sql-query tag` which turned to mysql so it should be the same thing.

Comment: Wait, "sql-query" aliases to "mysql"?  (Looking...)  Nope...looks like it aliases to "sql".  Not sure why "mysql" would show up; editing it out.

Comment: Oh opps I guess it was `mysql-query` was my mistake then.